# Redirect images from folder to folder

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I had a folder that contained 15000 images, i decided to put them in 10 folders.

The initial folder url where i had my 15000 images was :

```
www.mysite.com/images/games/
```

And the new folders' urls are :

```
www.mysite.com/images/games/1/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/2/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/3/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/4/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/5/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/6/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/7/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/8/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/9/  
www.mysite.com/images/games/10/
```

How can I redirect my images to match their correct folder to get rid of 404 errors?

Comment: Information is missing! You have to explain which images go to which folder. That can't be guessed. Your question is `How can I redirect my images to match their correct folder to get rid of 404 errors`.? But, what's the **correct folder**?`

Comment: Also, which httpd are you using? Apache? Nginx? IIS? Details matter.

Comment: I know which images go to which folder, but its a big list i cant make 15000 redirect in htacess, and iam using apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your expansion in the comments above:

> I know which images go to which folder, but its a big list

I suggest putting that list in a text file, and using find and replace (or `awk`?) to transform that list into `mod_redirect` rules, e.g.

```
Redirect /images/games/oldname /images/games/8/oldname
```

Then paste those into a configuration file. If there's no actual algorithm that determined how these got sorted into directories, there's no program that can redirect requests, because it would require a formula to work from.

Comment: +1 Excellent work trying to solve the unknown for the OP. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Much as I love to cite [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite), this is actually a case where `mod_rewrite` is called for.

**You don't say how you distributed your images between the ten new directories**, but I am assuming the images were numbered (e.g. `00001.png`, `00002.png`, ... `15000.png`). Then you used the last digit to determine which image goes into which folder, i.e. `00001.png` goes into the `1` directory, all the way up to `15000.png` which goes into the `10` directory (I think - why didn't you name it `0`?) That's what you did, right?

**You don't mention what server you're using on this site**, so I'm going to assume you're using Apache, right? In that case you'd edit the appropriate configuration file (I started trying to assume which one, but honestly it could be any one of four I can think of, depending on whether you have edit rights to the vhost configuration, or root on the server, or if you're on a Debian-flavored or Red-Hat-flavored distro, you *are* using Linux, right? **You didn't say**.) You'd make sure there's a `RewriteEngine On` in there somewhere, then you'd do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/games/(\d+)(\d)\.png$ /images/games/$2/$1$2.png
```

...except that you named the directory `10` instead of `0`, so all the ones ending in `0` are going to get misdirected. Maybe we should try this?

```
RewriteRule ^/images/games/(\d+0)\.png$ /images/games/10/$1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^/images/games/(\d+)([1-9])\.png$ /images/games/$2/$1$2.png [L]
```

...and catch the 0s first, then everything else.

I'd check this answer, but you haven't given us anywhere near enough information to know how.

Comment: To anyone else who finds this Q&A via search: for pity's sake number the directories 0..9 and not 1..10, and tell us a bit about your server environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer brother, i forgot to mention that all images had a specific name , example : myimage15_33 , greatday_today

Comment: If there is no algorithm for how you distributed the files amongst the directories, there is no practical way to redirect requests for them. If there is an algorithm, spill, please.